# Cannot deploy fresh create-react-app on Github Pages

Tags: reactjs, github

just finished a huge app and tried to deploy it on github but it started throwing 404 errors. I tried to create a fresh new one with just one change in the HTML (just to see that is customized) and it's throwing the same error. The dev version works, the production not.

Here is the error:

> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome->
> extension://hgmhmanijnjhaffoampdlllchpolkdnj/js/lib/purify.min.js.map:
> HTTP error: status code
>
> 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME favicon.ico:1 GET
> https://kirilchristov.github.io/favicon.ico 404 manifest.json:1 GET
> https://kirilchristov.github.io/manifest.json 404 manifest.json:1
> Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.

Here is a link to the repo: [Github Repo](https://github.com/kirilchristov/renker)

Here is the package.json with the scripts:

```js
{
  "home":"https://kirilchristov.github.io/renker",
  "name": "gr",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy":"gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you set your repo settings to serve gh-pages from root? I checked your gh-pages branch and the error and it looks like the server doesn't return from root

Comment: Yes @Dominik. Just checked it. It serves from the root folder

Comment: Have you enabled gh-pages in settings? I can't see the action environment listed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need three things for CRA to work on gh-pages

1. A branch with the prod files (default is `gh-pages`)

   ✅ You have that (I checked)
2. Settings enabling gh-pages and select the branch if not default and serve from `root`

   ✅ You have that as well, you say
3. The `homepage` key inside your `package.json`

   ❌ You have `home` instead of `homepage` https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#building-for-relative-paths

Try fixing that in your `package.json`

```json
{
  "homepage":"https://kirilchristov.github.io/renker",
  "name": "gr",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy":"gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Than you a lot. It was right before my eyes :( THank you